# How do I animate a character with dangling chain

Tags: animation, physics, bones

I have a fully rigged character and I would like to attach some loose parts to it, including a chain. How do I set this up, so the chain would freely 'dangle' from the character, following forces like gravity and the character's movements / momentum?
I was thinking I'd setup parts along Bezier curve, then link them by bones. The first bone would parent to a character mesh. But then how do I set this up, so when I animate the character, the chain follows the character's movement's realistically? Is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: Check out blender rigid bodies: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.66/Rigid_Body_Simulation

Comment: Use bullet physics. This tutorial http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/quick-tutorial-make-a-wrecking-ball-with-rigid-body-physics/#.U77BiPldV8E perfectly details everything you would need to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to enable rigid body from the physics tb for each chain link. Set the one you want to animate as passive all others to active. The collision shape must be *Mesh*.

[image]

Settings for the links:

[image]
[image]

To control the passive link by an armature you could add a *Copy Location Contrained*
[image]

[image]

If the chain breaks in the simulation increase the *Solver iterations* from the *Scene / Rigid Body World* settings and click *Free Bake* followed by *Bake All Dynamics*.

[image]

Demo [.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/30378)