# Intersected meshes make chain break

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

When I use Rigid Body physics and the meshes intersect each other, like the picture, the chain breaks when simulation (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) is done. I use 'mesh' as collision shape and increased the solver iterations and steps per second. What could I do to make the chain not break when I do the simulation? Thanks :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you add the .blend? Maybe lowering the mass of the objects could help (they are quit thin) I had this when animating a chain it teared off until I tweaked some params, unfortunately the my .blend is gone: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13916/how-do-i-animate-a-character-with-dangling-chain

Comment: This is the blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36320

Comment: I made the meshes heavier, because I thought that more mass means stronger connection, at least that's what I've learned :)

Comment: My Blender crashed so I updated to 2.74 and it still is freezing with you file. Check the Sensitivity param it should be > 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I had no luck with your file I created someting compareable.
Getting this working is tricky. You need to find balanced parameters most important are mass and sensitivty. 
A mass of 100 is way to much and sensitivity should be > 0, e.g. 0.01 (probably blender units).

[image]

With a mass of 1.0 the simulation breaks after 90 frames:

[image]

When the mass of the second ring only is increased to 2 it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you made the first chainlink 'active', but unchecked 'dynamic' right? Or did you make it 'passive'? But my chainlinks are more complex, does it make it more difficult to tune the parameters?

Comment: @FacebFaceb The first one is set to passive otherwise the whole chain would fall down.

Comment: Yes, but if you make the first chainlink active, but turn off 'dynamic', it won't fall down and the chain has less chance to break