# Chain breaks when animation is played

Tags: mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have made a chain of toruses, when I apply rigid body physics to it, it breaks as soon as I play animation.
I have tried scaling it up but does not help.
Please help me fix it.

Blender file is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5aZVQjlGn3uem44NVFoZ040SFk/view?usp=sharing
Chain is in 2nd layer.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/intersected-meshes-make-chain-break

Comment: Please upload all blends [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try increasing the steps per second, and solver iterations
Or try increasing the weight of some of the links

Comment: no it does not help, I increased the steps per second to 285 and solver iterations to 92 now it just explodes faster.