# Ring on a necklace model

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a cloth string covered with a skin to replicate a necklace.

Now I want to add a pendant. I am using a torus only to try and simulate the interactions first.

I have added a rigid body to both the skin object and torus, and added a rigid constraint to both and associated each object to each other, but they pass through.

Any advice?

Please see attached blend file

I have changed the parameters to try and make this more simple - made 2 soft body interactions, but cant make them seem or act in a solid fashion - any tips or advice? See second blend file.

Okay update - used cloth and collision for both objects and they interact better - but the torus is still soft, rather than hard - how to I make an object retain its shape when it interacts with a cloth object? See 3rd blend file

4th Update

Got a torus to interact with a serious of rigid body chains, however they are not movable - See 4th blend file

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't see the link to the attached blend file? Where can I access it from?

Comment: Ive been trying to upload it..... wont allow any files larger than 30mb

Comment: Are you trying to use giant cow films blend exchange?

Comment: @nascentSpace yes

Comment: See now - uploaded

Comment: For some reason now my cloth/skin is falling..... it was stable before on the pinned nodes

Comment: @allenSimpson - they are both set as mesh.... see file

Comment: I'll delete then, I was just looking at this really quickly

Answer (score 2):

I found this [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/intersected-meshes-make-chain-break) helpful.

1. I got rid of the Rigid Body Constraints.  They were doing nothing.
2. I set Torus.013 (center link) RB to active, mass of 0.5kg, margin 0.5m
3. Torus.026 (pendant) margin to 1m.

I believe that is all.   Here is the modified file, far from perfect: [image]

Comment: Cheers for the link....

Comment: I have the chain (rigid bodies) interacting with a torus (rigid body) - my goal is to have a cloth/skin object that acts like a string (necklace) with the torus as a pendent - this is the difficulty.... I was using rigid ones to try and get an idea - the soft object interacting with rigid one is my goal

Comment: BTW, if you want to "accept" my answer, I'll get the bounty points.  Not begging (oh plz oh plz!!) ;)

Comment: I would if it solved my issue lol .... i am looking for a skin/string/thread/necklace object that interacts with a torus... thanks for your tips, but ultimately doesnt solve my enquire and what i am struggling with

Answer (score 2):

I would say you will have to stay with cloth sim only if you want to use Cloth Sim string. Using Rigid Body would not work because it is calculated before cloth simulation.

Here is an example of Cloth Sim ...

- String - Cloth Sim + Collision
- Ring - Cloth Sim (Leather)

[image]

[image]

Anyway - collision with such thin string would be always difficult to do.

Comment: Awesome! I will try and replicate this tomorrow!